# design datagridview with search at first row

Tags: c#, search, datagridview

I'm newbie in C#. I want to create a datagridview with search at first row like this photo.
someone can tell me how to do it?
Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljFZX.png)

Answer (score 1):

For a newbie it would be easier to just stack two datagridview on top of each other in the ui. Provide one empty row in the first and no rows in the second. Make so users cannot add or delete rows to either. When the user changes the top row and clicks search, take the values and do the search and put the results to the bottom dgv